# Passing different object models as a parameter to a method in scala

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, covariance, subtype

I've really struggled with *type relationships in scala* and how to use them effectively. I am currently trying to understand how I would use them to only edit certain fields in a *Mongo Collection*. This means passing a particular *object* containing only those fields to a method which (after reading [about variances](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html)) I thought that I could do like this:

```
   abstract class DocClass
   case class DocPart1(oId: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, other: String) extends DocClass
   case class DocPart2(city: String, country: String) extends DocClass
```

With the method that calls a more generic method as:

```
   def updateMultipleFields(oId: Option[BSONObjectID], dataModel: DocClass): Future[Result] = serviceClientDb.updateFields[T](collectionName, dataModel, oId)
   // updateFields updates the collection by passing *dataModel* into the collection, i.e. Json.obj("$set" -> dataModel)
```

So `dataModel` can be a `DocPart1` or `DocPart2` object. I'm eager not to use a 
*type parameter* on `updateMultipleFields` (as this [interesting article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/scala-type-system-parameterized-types-variances-part-1/) may suggest) as this leads me to further issues in passing these to this method in other files in the project. I'm doing this to abide with DRY and in order to maintain efficient database operations.

### I've gone round in circles with this one - can anyone shed any light on this?

**Edited after @SerGr's comments**

So to be completely clear; I'm using Play/Scala/ReactiveMongo Play JSON (as [documented here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html)) and I have a MongoDB collection with lots of fields.

```
   case class Doc(oId: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, city: String, country: String, city: String, continent: String, region: String, region: String, latitude: Long, longitude: Long)
```

To create a new document I have auto-mapped `Doc` (above) to the collection structure (in Play - [like this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated)) and created a form (to insert/update the *collection*) - all working well!

But when editing a document; I would like to update only some fields (so that all of the fields are not updated). I have therefore created multiple `case classes` to divide these fields into smaller models (like the examples of `DocPart1` & `DocPart2`) and mapped the form data to just one. This has led me to pass these as a parameter to the `updateMultipleFields` method as shown above. I hope that this makes more sense.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you have a single object and a few different sets of fields that are updated in different scenarios and you want to group every such set in an explicit type? Or do you have some collection that for some reason stores objects of different types that should be updated differently? Or is there some other scenario for this kind of code?

Comment: @SerGr - thanks for the response. Please see comments and if you need further clarification let me know. ATB

Comment: Jesus, could you also say what library you use to access Mongo? It is important to understand what API it provides for such partial updates.

Comment: @SerGr - I'm using **_ReactiveMongo Play JSON_** as [documented here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you need. Still here is some code that might be it. Assume we have our `FullDoc` class defined as:

```scala
case class FullDoc(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, other: String)
```

and we have 2 partial updates defined as:

```scala
sealed trait BaseDocPart

case class DocPart1(name: String) extends BaseDocPart

case class DocPart2(other: String) extends BaseDocPart
```

Also assume we have an accessor to our Mongo collection:

```scala
def docCollection: Future[JSONCollection] = ...
```

So if I understand your requirements, what you need is something like this:

```scala
def update[T <: BaseDocPart](oId: BSONObjectID, docPart: T)(implicit format: OFormat[T]) = {
  docCollection.flatMap(_.update(BSONDocument("_id" -> oId),
    JsObject(Seq("$set" -> Json.toJson(docPart)))))
}
```

Essentially the main trick is to use generic `T <: BaseDocPart` and pass `implicit format: OFormat[T]` so that we can convert our specific child of `BaseDocPart` to JSON even after type erasure.

And here is some additional test code (that I used in my console application)

```scala
  implicit val fullFormat = Json.format[FullDoc]
  implicit val part1Format = Json.format[DocPart1]
  implicit val part2Format = Json.format[DocPart2]

  def insert(id: Int) = {
    val fullDoc = FullDoc(None, s"fullDoc_$id", s"other_$id")
    val insF: Future[WriteResult] = docCollection.flatMap(_.insert(fullDoc))
    val insRes = Await.result(insF, 2 seconds)
    println(s"insRes = $insRes")
  }

  def loadAndPrintAll() = {
    val readF = docCollection.flatMap(_.find(Json.obj()).cursor[FullDoc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect(100, Cursor.FailOnError[Vector[FullDoc]]()))
    val readRes = Await.result(readF, 2 seconds)
    println(s"readRes =\n${readRes.mkString("\n")}")
  }

  def loadRandomDocument(): FullDoc = {
    val readF = docCollection.flatMap(_.find(Json.obj()).cursor[FullDoc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect(100, Cursor.FailOnError[Vector[FullDoc]]()))
    val readRes = Await.result(readF, 2 seconds)
    readRes(Random.nextInt(readRes.length))
  }

  def updateWrapper[T <: BaseDocPart](oId: BSONObjectID, docPart: T)(implicit writer: OFormat[T]) = {
    val updateRes = Await.result(update(oId, docPart), 2 seconds)
    println(s"updateRes = $updateRes")
  }

  // pre-fill with some data    
  insert(1)
  insert(2)
  insert(3)
  insert(4)
  val newId: Int = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - 1511464148000L) / 100).toInt
  println(s"newId = $newId")

  val doc21: FullDoc = loadRandomDocument()
  println(s"doc21 = $doc21")
  updateWrapper(doc21._id.get, DocPart1(s"p1_modified_$newId"))

  val doc22: FullDoc = loadRandomDocument()
  println(s"doc22 = $doc22")
  updateWrapper(doc22._id.get, DocPart2(s"p2_modified_$newId"))

  loadAndPrintAll()
```